# Создание JSON объекта

Tags: c#, json

Как создать JSON объект не из заранее заготовленного класса, а из некоторых переменных ?

Чтобы это как то не так выглядело:

```
string json = "{\"param1\":\"val\",\"param2\":\"val\"}";
```

А как то так:

```
string json = [0][param1 = val1][0][param2 = val2][0][param3 = val3][1][param4 = val4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй словарь или анонимный класс. Вроде как-то так:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, object> { {"param1", "val"}, {"param2", "val"} })
```

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { param1="val", param2="val" })
```

Comment: Спасибо! - То что нужно было.